# Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Hey Getting the error below  I run the webpack command:
$> webpack --mode "development"

**stack trace:**

```
Version: webpack 4.17.2
Time: 1357ms
Built at: 09/10/2018 8:13:26 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.37 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[0] fs (ignored) 15 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./wwwroot/Source/Styles/app.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./wwwroot/Source/Styles/app.css 165 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./wwwroot/Source/Styles/site.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./wwwroot/Source/Styles/site.css 207 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {main} [built]
[./wwwroot/Source/Script/app.ts] 221 bytes {main} [built]
[./wwwroot/Source/Script/site.ts] 274 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./wwwroot/Source/Styles/app.css] 1.06 KiB {main} [built]
[./wwwroot/Source/Styles/site.css] 1.07 KiB {main} [built]
    + 30 hidden modules

ERROR in ./wwwroot/Source/Script/site.ts 25:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (25:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| class Animal {
>     name: string;
|     constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
|     move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
 @ ./wwwroot/Source/Script/app.ts 4:0-16
```

It seems it does not recognize the properties in any of my classes when transpiling.

** ts code **

```
class Animal {
   name: string;
   constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
   move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
     console.log(`${this.name} moved 
     ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
  }
}
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./app/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "ExposureAPI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wbp": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1",
    "ts-loader": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/simplemde": "^1.11.7",
    "simplemde": "^1.11.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        entry: './wwwroot/Source/Script/app.ts',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/App'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: ['node_modules'],
                    use: [
                        { loader: "style-loader" },
                        { loader: "css-loader" }
                    ]
                }]
        }


    };
```

Thanks

Comment: What if you add `"include": [
        "wwwroot/**/*"
    ]` to your tsconfig? Btw, you have `module` twice in your webpack config

Comment: @zerkms it was the double module thing (I'm total webpack newb ) please set that as the answer and Ill give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it happened because you have two `module` properties in the webpack config object.

Given JS objects can only hold one value per key - one value would be lost. And in this particular case the latter was overwriting the former, so webpack ended up configured without typescript loader config at all.

Comment: I agree. In general whatever the specific case would be, if one gets "Unexpected token" they should get a look at the webpack config file. Period.