# Why are suddenly packages installed by npm not plain old javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have been working with [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet/v/3.1.0) for a couple of weeks without any issue. I had the bad idea to clean my `node_module` directory and since then I get the following error while bundling my app (with webpack 4):

```
[error] ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
[error] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
[error] File was processed with these loaders:
[error]  * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js
[error] You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
[error] |   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
[error] |     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
[error] >       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
[error] |       element.instance.setStyle(options);
[error] |       optionsRef.current = options;
```

I understand that `source-map-loader` is not happy about the nullish coalescing operator found line 10. So I simply added `babel-loader` before and now everything works fine as expected.

But I still would like to understand the mess with NPM:

- 1. I am new to the Javascript world, but shouldn't library authors provide plain old javascript on NPM??
- 2. The funny thing is that after recovering my deleted `node_modules` directory (I had kept a copy), I found out that line 10 is replaced by `const options = (_props$pathOptions = props.pathOptions) != null ? _props$pathOptions : {};`... How is it possible that the exact same version of react-leaflet (v3.1.0) was a couple of weeks ago plain old javascript and now it is not??

Note: I use node 14.17.0 and npm 6.14.13

Comment: Um, it is plain old JavaScript, just not a version of JavaScript that you support.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a NodeJS versioning issue -- it seems that the nullish coalescing operator only became available in NodeJS in [version 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). If you upgrade to NodeJS version 14+, this error should go away. Alternatively, you could use lower versions of these packages that don't include this operator, if that works for you.

Comment: Okay, strange. Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268320/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token

Comment: Nope. I have only one module in my config.